# How can I change the url webClient based on reactor context

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient, spring-reactor

Based on a country already added on a webfilter, I need to modify the request to a different server.

I already added the context with the webfilter to the chain, I can see it here, but I didn't find how to modify the received clientRequest based on the signal context on the chain.
If anybody already found a way to do that and can help:

```java
return webClient
                .filter(
                        ExchangeFilterFunction
                                .ofRequestProcessor(
                                        new Function<ClientRequest, Mono<ClientRequest>>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public Mono<ClientRequest> apply(ClientRequest clientRequest) {
                                                return Mono.just(
                                                        ClientRequest.from(clientRequest).build())
                                                        .doOnEach(new Consumer<Signal<ClientRequest>>() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void accept(Signal<ClientRequest> signal) {
                                                                var countryContext = signal.getContext()
                                                                        .getOrEmpty(CountryContext.COUNTRY_CONTEXT_HEADER_REST).get();
                                                                System.out.println(countryContext);
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                            }
                                        }
                                )
                ).build();
```

Comment: I probably would not have gone down that route of modifying the request based on a context var. But hey, I don't know your exact requirements. The question is completely legit, though, and I don't understand the down vote...

Answer (score 2):

I found out a way, it's implementing a custom`ExchangeFilterFunction`, and using `Mono.subscriberContext()`

```java
WebClient
    .filter((request, next) -> Mono.subscriberContext()
            .flatMap(ctx -> {
                        ClientRequest cr = ClientRequest.from(request)
                                // manipulate request to the new prefix server
                                // from the ctx signal.
                                .build();
                        return next.exchange(cr);
                    }
                ))
```

Answer (score 1):

`Mono.subscriberContext()` is deprecated and will be removed in Spring Reactor 3.5. Use `Mono.deferContextual()` instead.

In your case:

```
WebClient.filter((request, next) -> 
  Mono.deferContextual(ctx -> {
    ClientRequest cr = ClientRequest.from(request)
    // manipulate request to the new prefix server
    // from the ctx signal.
    .build();
    return next.exchange(cr);
  })
);
```